# Copying a subarray into another array

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
int copy(char d[],char e[],int n);
int main(void)
{

    char a[20]="Nice to meet you";
    char b[10];
    copy(a+5,b,4);
    return 0;
}

int copy(char d[],char e[],int n)
{
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
    e[i]=d[i];
   }
 printf("%s\n",e);
 return 0;
}
```

Here `d` points to `a+5` and `e` points to `b`. Here I understood that the output would be "`to m`".
My question is: in `copy` function if I initialize `i` to run from `1` to `n-1` instead of `0` to `n-1`, why is it not giving the desired output?
I expected the new output to be "`o m`".

Comment: No 0 termination on string e so that is undefined behavior for a start.

Comment: Your variable and parameter names don't give the reader any hint about which one is which. Names like `d` and `e` - what do those mean? Which is the `source` and which is the `target`? Yes, I know I can read the function code and figure it out, but the purpose of names is to make these things clear.

Comment: `char b[10];` --> `char b[10] = {0};`

Comment: @MichaelGeary-- agree about suggestion for better names, and to add one more stumbling block to understanding, string handling functions typically place the target in the first position, but this code inverts that convention....

Comment: @BLUEPIXY while that is a fix, I don't think that is the right suggestion, because it would break if copy is called again with say a smaller size. I think the ideal solution would be to add `0` at the end in the `copy` function.

Comment: Your `copy()` function could be generally useful if it didn't print the result of copying too.  If the function only returns `0`, there's not really any point in making conscientious code check the return value.  Your function should be declared with return type `void` and with the `return 0;` deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you loop with `i` in `copy` from `1` to `n - 1`, then after calling `copy(a + 5, b, 4)` in `main`, `b[0]` will still be uninitialised, so accessing it is undefined behaviour (you aren't making sure the string in `b` ends in a `'\0'`, either). Even if it weren't, it would still be there; for it to print "o m" you would have to start reading from `b + 1`, or do the assignment in `copy` like `e[i - 1] = d[i]` (and make sure to nul-terminate it if you're going to treat it as a string after, or treating it as a nul-terminated string will have it read past the end into uninitialised territory and similarly invoke undefined behaviour).